# ASP.NET MVC background work - Best practice

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application which is supposed to receive and send messages to Android smartphones. The way I have currently implemented it is by using a message broker (RabbitMQ in this case) and let that broker handle the communications between the backend and the smartphones.

In the ASP.NET code I am creating a thread which is run at the beginning of the application in global.asax (I have seen some people who recommends this, maybe I am doing it wrong...). This thread is in charge of listening to the messages that the broker receives and then process them.

My question is: is this a good practice in terms of handling external messages in an ASP.NET application? This is the first time I program this kind of applications and I don't know if I am doing the things right. Does anybody know another ways to receive messages from an external device in ASP.NET? Again, keep in mind I'm very new to ASP.NET, maybe I am asking something stupid but I just need some information about this.

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you really want to use a full fledged service bus.  have you looked into nservicebus or masstransit.  you can back plane the bus with rabbitmq.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but where is the bus in an ASP.NET application? How is it defined?

Comment: Here's the homepage for MassTransit https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit

Comment: Ok, I will take a look into it. Thanks.

Comment: For subtleties around keeping the background process alive, see these articles: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx ; http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has a similar question I will answer how I made it work. At the end I used HangFire (http://hangfire.io/), it is quite easy to configure, just need to add this code below in Startup.Auth file:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("db_name");

        app.UseHangfireServer();
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
```

And the following code to start the background task:

```
        var storage = new SqlServerStorage("db_name");
        var client = new BackgroundJobClient(storage);
        client.Enqueue(() => rabbitInstance.MethodXYZ());
```

I hope this solution is helpful for more people.